# provider.on() method for listening to events by multiple wallet addresses

Tags: web3js, ethers.js

Currently, web3.js is able to listen for multiple addresses' logs by passing in an array on the .

```js
    const wallets = ["0x031414134", "0x19351351", "0x130413515"];
    const subscription = web3.eth
        .subscribe(
            "logs",
            {
                address: wallets,
                topics: [],
                // topics: [null],
            },
            (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        )
        .on("data", async (transaction) => {
            console.log(transaction);
        });
```

Is there an equivalent for ethers.js?

**NOTE: For my purposes, it is not sufficient to create a new `subscription` variable while iterating over the `wallets` array.**

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't possible. Though, if you know which wallet you shall be listening to and at which moment, you can put it according to its index and listen to it at that particular instance.

Comment: @BrijeshAgal Thank you